# How to simulate mouse press with shift in xkbcomp

Tags: x11, xkb

I have a mouse with a small built-in keyboard.
I'd like to map one key as combination of "Shift-MiddleButton". This combination is used in Blender for navigation.

I don't know how to emulate multiple actions in xkb_comp section.

I was able to simulate middle button, but I need Shift too.

```
xkb_compatibility "cmp" {
   virtual_modifiers Shift;
   interpret Pointer_EnableKeys { 
       action = LockControls(controls=MouseKeys);
   };

   interpret.repea t= True;
   interpret 1 { action = PointerButton(button=2); };
   interpret.repeat = False;
   indicator "Scroll Lock" {
        indicatorDrivesKeyboard;
        controls = MouseKeys;
   };
};

xkb_symbols "remote" {
    key <AE01> { [1, 1] };
};
```

I tried multiple actions:

```
interpret 1 { 
   action = SetMods(modifiers=Shift); 
   action = PointerButton(button=2); 
};
```

PointerButton doesn't have modifiers argument.

Comment: If it doesn't work in xkb_comp, you can also try `xte`. BTW, `repea t=` looks like a typo, but I'm not sure it it would break anything.